# how to import data to mongodb with multiple index

Tags: mongodb, import, nosql, mean, studio3t

I am quite new to mongodb, I just created a `database` name `Test` and inside have a `collection` called `projects`
i have a json file which contain 2 projects like this :

```
{
  "-KutvlMPRHGWWTgk1Mh4" : {
    "isPrivate" : true,
    "proj_contact" : "blMufEZjv6ZmnugDlTruzGwmowI3",
    "proj_creator" : "blMufEZjv6ZmnugDlTruzGwmowI3",
    "proj_date" : "01/01/2017",
    "proj_des" : "this is a testing projectasfasfasgasg",
    "proj_name" : "Project",
    "proj_pi" : "qCQee2pWGeN9PD3FRXbJpdN7mHT2"
  },
  "-KvARDkcsCEKZgnM94xH" : {
    "isPrivate" : false,
    "proj_autho" : [ "Lei0ohIcMBbzVtcQD1AgU4wHBKR2", "OnjEOFSNVpf189J9hAaSFWOZdl42", "0DwfVUeMAraiRxFZTa6xyjn6sfx2", "WHjFSvEo45U7ULzwIQdnUz6ytXp1", "kKTWt36bIifrRzpqNP1l2Gnl3KU2" ],
    "proj_contact" : "kKTWt36bIifrRzpqNP1l2Gnl3KU2",
    "proj_creator" : "kKTWt36bIifrRzpqNP1l2Gnl3KU2",
    "proj_date" : "10/12/2017",
    "proj_des" : "this is a test :)",
    "proj_name" : "another test",
    "proj_pi" : "qCQee2pWGeN9PD3FRXbJpdN7mHT2"
  }
}
```

so I want to import this to the `projects collection`.
I was running this command

```
mongoimport --db Test --collection projects --file import-file.json
```

But the thing is the result i got is the mongodb create only **one index ( 1 id )** which contains the whole thing.

What i want is after importing , mongodb will create **2 different indexes ( 2 ids )** for each of the project above

This is the current result. I was using Studio 3T [image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing one curly braces(to nest object itself)

```
{
  {"-KutvlMPRHGWWTgk1Mh4" : {
"isPrivate" : true,
"proj_contact" : "blMufEZjv6ZmnugDlTruzGwmowI3",
"proj_creator" : "blMufEZjv6ZmnugDlTruzGwmowI3",
"proj_date" : "01/01/2017",
"proj_des" : "this is a testing projectasfasfasgasg",
"proj_name" : "Project",
"proj_pi" : "qCQee2pWGeN9PD3FRXbJpdN7mHT2"
}},
{"-KvARDkcsCEKZgnM94xH" : {
"isPrivate" : false,
"proj_autho" : [ "Lei0ohIcMBbzVtcQD1AgU4wHBKR2", "OnjEOFSNVpf189J9hAaSFWOZdl42", "0DwfVUeMAraiRxFZTa6xyjn6sfx2", "WHjFSvEo45U7ULzwIQdnUz6ytXp1", "kKTWt36bIifrRzpqNP1l2Gnl3KU2" ],
"proj_contact" : "kKTWt36bIifrRzpqNP1l2Gnl3KU2",
"proj_creator" : "kKTWt36bIifrRzpqNP1l2Gnl3KU2",
"proj_date" : "10/12/2017",
"proj_des" : "this is a test :)",
"proj_name" : "another test",
"proj_pi" : "qCQee2pWGeN9PD3FRXbJpdN7mHT2"
 }}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[By default, monogoimport assumes a special structure for a file to import from: similar to JSON format except that only one document per line is allowed with no comma after each of them](https://zaiste.net/importing_json_into_mongodb)

```
{
  "-KutvlMPRHGWWTgk1Mh4" : {
    "isPrivate" : true,
    "proj_contact" : "blMufEZjv6ZmnugDlTruzGwmowI3",
    "proj_creator" : "blMufEZjv6ZmnugDlTruzGwmowI3",
    "proj_date" : "01/01/2017",
    "proj_des" : "this is a testing projectasfasfasgasg",
    "proj_name" : "Project",
    "proj_pi" : "qCQee2pWGeN9PD3FRXbJpdN7mHT2"
  }
  "-KvARDkcsCEKZgnM94xH" : {
    "isPrivate" : false,
    "proj_autho" : [ "Lei0ohIcMBbzVtcQD1AgU4wHBKR2", "OnjEOFSNVpf189J9hAaSFWOZdl42", "0DwfVUeMAraiRxFZTa6xyjn6sfx2", "WHjFSvEo45U7ULzwIQdnUz6ytXp1", "kKTWt36bIifrRzpqNP1l2Gnl3KU2" ],
    "proj_contact" : "kKTWt36bIifrRzpqNP1l2Gnl3KU2",
    "proj_creator" : "kKTWt36bIifrRzpqNP1l2Gnl3KU2",
    "proj_date" : "10/12/2017",
    "proj_des" : "this is a test :)",
    "proj_name" : "another test",
    "proj_pi" : "qCQee2pWGeN9PD3FRXbJpdN7mHT2"
  }
}
```

Comment: If i change to yours , it said this is no longer a valid json file

Comment: validate here https://jsonlint.com/ got error like this : Error: Parse error on line 1:
{ {  "-KutvlMPRHGWWTg
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'

Comment: https://zaiste.net/importing_json_into_mongodb  By default, monogoimport assumes a special structure for a file to import from: similar to JSON format except that only one document per line is allowed with no comma after each of them

Comment: referring to the docs,  the open and close should be square bracket, then i use -jsonArray and it works . Thanks men